# Find maximum value of $\int_{1}^3\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$ if $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx=0$ and also $-1\leq f(x)\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, differential

Let $f$ be function such that $$\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx=0$$ and $$-1\leq f(x)\leq 1$$ Then find the maximum value of $$\int_{1}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$

My Attempt:

I wonder if this approach is correct or not.

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} -c, 1\le x\le a \\ 1, a\le x<3 \end{cases}$$
As per the constraint $$c=\frac{3-a}{a-1}$$
Let $$G(a)=\int_{1}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\int_{1}^{a}\frac{-c}{x}dx+\int_{a}^{3}\frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{2}{1-a}\ln a+\ln 3$$
$$G'(a)=\frac{1-a+a\ln a}{a(1-a)^2}$$
After putting $G'(a)=0$

I am not able to solve for $a$

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ for $x\leq 2$ and $-1$ otherwise?

Comment: Yes. Very nice but how to justify taking this as f(x).

Comment: You want to put the largest possible weight to the lowest values of $x$ subject to the constraint that you need to allocate the complement to the rest. The largest weight is one, and for $f(x)$ to average to zero, the largest value of $x$ that can still be covered by this weight is $2$. Something along these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, 
I will generalize.

Let $f$ be function such that 
$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$
and 
$|f(x)|\leq 1$.

Find the best bound of 
$|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx|$
where
$g(x) > 0$
and
$g'(x) < 0$.

The original problem is
$a=1, b=3, g(x) = \dfrac1{x}$.

For
$g(a) > c > g(b)$,

$\begin{array}\\
|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx|
&=|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx-c\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|\\
&=|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)(g(x)-c)dx|\\
&\le\int_{a}^{b}|g(x)-c|dx\\
&\le\int_{a}^{g^{-1}(c)}|g(x)-c|dx+\int_{g^{-1}(c)}^{b}|g(x)-c|dx\\
&=\int_{a}^{g^{-1}(c)}(g(x)-c)dx+\int_{g^{-1}(c)}^{b}(c-g(x))dx\\
&=c(b-2g^{-1}(c)+a)+\int_{a}^{g^{-1}(c)}g(x)dx-\int_{g^{-1}(c)}^{b}g(x)dx\\
&=c(b-2h(c)+a)+\int_{a}^{h(c)}g(x)dx-\int_{h(c)}^{b}g(x)dx
\qquad h(x) = g^{-1}(x)\\
&=c(b-2h(c)+a)+G(h(c))-G(a)-G(b)+G(h(c))
\qquad G'(x) = g(x)\\
&=c(b-2h(c)+a)-(G(a)+G(b)-2G(h(c)))\\
\end{array}
$

We want to minimize this.

$\begin{array}\\
r(c)
&=c(b-2h(c)+a)-(G(a)+G(b)-2G(h(c)))\\
&=c(b+a)-2ch(c)-(G(a)+G(b)-2G(h(c)))\\
\text{so}\\
r'(c)
&=(b+a)-2(h(c)+ch'(c))+2h'(c)G'(h(c))\\
&=(b+a)-2(h(c)+ch'(c))+2h'(c)g(h(c))\\
&=(b+a)-2(h(c)+ch'(c))+2h'(c)c\\
&=(b+a)-2h(c)\\
\end{array}
$

We want
$r'(c) = 0$,
so
$b+a
= 2h(c)
=2g^{-1}(c)
$
so
$c
=g(\frac{b+a}{2})
$.

For the problem,
$g(c) = \dfrac1{c}$
so
$c
=\dfrac{2}{b+a}
$.

Then,
since
$G(c) = \ln(c)$
and $ch(c) = 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
r(c)
&=c(b+a)-2ch(c)-(G(a)+G(b)-2G(h(c)))\\
&=\dfrac{2}{b+a}(b+a)-2-(\ln(a)+\ln(b)-2\ln(\dfrac{b+a}{2}))\\
&=-(\ln(a)+\ln(b)-2\ln(\dfrac{b+a}{2}))\\
&=\ln(\dfrac{(b+a)^2}{4ab})\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=1, b=3$
this is
$\ln(\frac{16}{12})
=\ln(\frac{4}{3})
=\ln(4)-\ln(3)
$.

Comment: Amazing $ {} {} {}$

Comment: As usual, I prefer to solve an infinite number of problems at once. Glad you like it.

Comment: The advantage of that in my opinion is that you usually "wash away" some of the irrelevant details of the specific questions and focus more on the underlying idea

Answer (score 8):

This was an exercise in the 2014 Putnam and the trick is to write for a parameter $a>0$,
\begin{split}
\left\lvert\int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}x\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert &= \left\lvert\int_1^3\frac{f(x)}x\,\mathrm dx -\int_1^3\frac{f(x)}a\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert\\
&=\left\lvert\int_1^3 f(x)\left(\frac1x-\frac1a\right)\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert \\
&\le\int_1^3 \lvert f(x)\rvert\left\lvert\frac1x-\frac1a\right\rvert\,\mathrm dx \\
&\le\int_1^3 \left\lvert\frac1x-\frac1a\right\rvert\,\mathrm dx \\
&=\ln\left(\frac{a^2}3\right)+\frac4a-2.
\end{split}

Minimizing the last expression with $a=2$ we get $$\left\lvert\int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}x\,\mathrm dx\right\rvert\le\ln(4)-\ln(3).$$

Equality is achieved for the function suggested by @Student in the comments: $f(x)=1$ on $[1,2]$ and $f(x)=-1$ on $[2,3]$.

Comment: Can I ask you why the following is wrong?
Using that $x\in[1,3]$ and $f(x)\leq1$ it follows that $\frac{f(x)}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$ and so $\int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x} \text{d}x \leq \int_1^3 \frac{1}{x} \text{d}x =\ln3$.
Also where are you using the fact that $\int_1^3 f(x) \text{d}x=0$?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Dunkelheit : Your argument is correct but it gives a weaker bound since $\ln(4)-\ln(3)=\ln(4/3)<\ln(3)$. (The $\ln(3)$ cannot be achieved so it is not a maximal value). I am using the fact that $\int_1^3 f=0$ when adding the term $\int_1^3\frac{f(x)}a\,\mathrm dx$. Cheers

Comment: I see, last doubt: how can we prove that $\ln 3$ can't be achieved? Thanks again for your courtesy.

Comment: @Dunkelheit $\ln3$ can't be achieved simply because we know the integral is always less or equal than $\ln4-\ln3$ which is strictly less than $\ln 3$ 